# How to set button position programmatically?

Tags: android

In my code I create button two programmatically how do I set is position to center of screen programmatically? This is my image of screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yCSd.jpg  submit button(button2) is create just below forloop button how do I set is position to center of screen?

```
    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(MainActivity1.this);
    scroll.setLayoutParams(new  
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));         

    btnLO = new LinearLayout(MainActivity1.this);   
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new  
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // button margins
    paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // button height/width *pixels*
    paramsLO.height = 75;
    paramsLO.width = 75;

    btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    btnLO.setBackgroundColor(5); // not working correctly

    //buttons
    for (i = 0;i < reqdata.length;i++)
    {
        LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(this);
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        final Button b1 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity1.this);

        li.addView(b1, paramsLO);        
        li.addView(imageView, paramsLO);
        btnLO.addView(li);

        b1.setText(reqdata[i].getSpinnerText());

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                imageView1 = imageView;
                Intent pictureActionIntent = new
                  Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 

                pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new  
                File(SDCARD_ROOT_PATH + SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD,IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME)));  

                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,CAMERA_PICTURE);
                b1.setClickable(false);
            }   
        });
    }

    final Button b2 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
    b2.setText("Submit");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            long visitID = dbConnector.saveVisit();

            for (i =0;i <reqdata.length;i++)
            {
                dbConnector.saveVisitDetail(listByte.get(i),visitID,Long.valueOf(reqdata[i]
                  .getValue()).longValue());
            }
        }
    }); 
    btnLO.addView(b2, paramsLO);
    btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    scroll.addView(btnLO);

    this.addContentView(scroll, new LayoutParams());
}
```

Comment: how i use only for button two??help me plz

Comment: Here is androids documentation on scroll view "A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll"... In your case that child is Linear Layout. You are left with two options: (1) use Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout and position buttons wherever you want (2) use Relative Layout, add only button two and add this relative layout in your original linear layout. I would recommend option 1. Do you want me to post the code for any of these options ?

Comment: how i use relative layout only for button two and add in linearlayout??

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use the `RelativeLayout` as your base layout and add all other children views to this layout using the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class for setting the layout parameters.

The `RelativeLayout.Layoutparams.left` and `RelativeLayout.Layoutparams.top` attributes can be your (x,y) co- 
ordinates on the base view.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity xml, copy paste the following in the desired button component:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginleft="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
```

play only with the numbers and I'm sure u'll get the hang of it :)